# PyCharm ignores debugging breakpoints in interactive prompt

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints, prompt

Is there a way to make debugging in PyCharm respect breakpoints when 'injecting' code into a running program via the python prompt?

[image: Breakpoint ignored in python prompt]

The top half of the screenshot shows the breakpoint in line #250 and the bottom half shows the execution of `get_similarity()` in the python prompt. However, the execution does not stop at line #250 as intended.

*Is there a way for code that has been executed from the prompt to respect breakpoints?*

In case it is relevant, I am using Python 3 and PyCharm 2016.3.2.

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcOCNgXXhmE